# Nodemon won't detect changes if I run it with npm run

Tags: npm, nodemon, ts-node

I have the following command:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' -e ts --exec ts-node --esm src/index.ts"
  },
```

If I run `npm run dev` nodemon will start successfully, but If I update any of my .ts files inside the src folder, nodemon won't detect changes in the project and won't re-run the project.

Nevertheless, If I run `npx nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' -e ts --exec ts-node --esm src/index.ts` directly in my terminal, it will start successfully too, but this time it will actually detect changes in any of my .ts file in the src folder and re-run the project.

I have the following structure:

```
├─── .vscode/
│   └─── types.ts.code-snippets
├─── src/
│   ├─── entities/
│   │   └───...
│   ├─── resolvers/
│   │   └───...
│   └─── index.ts
├─── .gitignore
├─── backend-idea.yml
├─── package-lock.json
├─── package.json
└─── tsconfig.json
```

I tried to change `'src/**/*.ts'` to `"./src/**/*.ts"` and it worked exactly like before.

What could be the reason it only works If I execute directly in my terminal and not with `npm run dev`? I am in Windows 11, Node v19.9, Powershell 7.3.6. (pwd is in the root directory of the project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work I had to replace the `'` to `\"` & `"\`. So the script looks like that:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon --watch \"src/**/*.ts\" -e ts --exec ts-node --esm src/index.ts"
  },
```